# Retrofit adds extra params in json array

Tags: android, json, retrofit

I have an android app which process some json array details response from a backend. Inside the array for one element i have an extra boolean parameter called 'enforce_exclusivity' which is true for that specific array element. But after getting json response from retrofit, all those array elements contains the 'enforce_exclusivity'value which is false for those elements. I have added the response below.

Response send from Back end

```
{"courses": [
{
  "name": "xxx",
  "slug": "xxx"
},

{
  "enforce_exclusivity": true,
  "name": "xxx",
  "slug": "xxxx"
},}
```

Response Which My app shows is,

```
  {"courses": [{"enforce_exclusivity": false,"name": "xxx", "slug": "xxx"},{ "enforce_exclusivity": true,"name": "xxx", "slug": "xxxx"},}
```

Can anyone tell me why it is happening?

Comment: error in your json

Comment: Retrofit is not the problem. Your Gson Java class is

Comment: I am using gson 2.3.1. Any fixes for that?

Comment: if there is no parameter in the json then it takes default value default Boolean value is false.

Comment: Okay got it. Thanks